# How to update property value when call function TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi everyone I want to change a piece of JS code into TS code.

JS

```
function newState(name){
      var state ={
        name : name,
        age : 0
      } 
      return state
    }

function initStates() {  
 this.JamesState = newState('James')
 this.RoyState = newState('Roy');
 this.RoyState.age = 20;
}
```

TS

```
newPRYState(name){
  let state = {
      name : name,
      age : 0
  }
  return state
}

initStates() { 
   this.JamesState = newState('James')
   this.RoyState = newState('Roy');
   this.RoyState.age = 20; 
}
```

error: Type 'object' no property age

I want the result is 
name:James
age:0

name:Roy
age:20

Please tell me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to have type for all the variables while working with TS. Define the interface and set this type with the variable.

```
interface IState {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

newPRYState(name: string): IState {
  let state: IState = {
      name : name,
      age : 0
  }
  return state;
}

initStates() { 
   this.JamesState: IState = newState('James')
   this.RoyState: IState = newState('Roy');
   this.RoyState.age = 20; 
}
```

Comment: That's not necessarily true. You don't need to define an interface for it to work.

Comment: Yes, you can set `any` without defining an interface. Yet it's good practice to have `interface`.

Comment: Just realize I set type for already defined `thisRoyState.age`.

Comment: Javascript is perfectly valid typescript, you don't have to define types. That said, if you plan to not use types, you may just not use typescript at all.

Comment: @MikeS. Right. and the problem in the question is anyway related to type, as the return type of `newPRYState` method is an object, so the type of the `this.JamesState` and `this.RoyState` is automatically set to the object, thus the problem occurs in the compilation.